# How can I open a new Finder window from Spotlight?

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight

Can I open a Finder window from Spotlight? How so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can type in the name of your home folder.  That will have the same effect as making a new window in Finder (if your default new windows open with that folder).

---

Here are some other useful Finder keyboard shortcuts:

```
Shift + Command + H = open Home
Shift + Command + A = open Applications
Shift + Command + D = open Desktop
Shift + Command + O = open Documents
Shift + Command + U = open Utilities
Shift + Command + G = go to folder... (provide Unix path)
```

Comment: Seems like this is the best answer, but see my comment to @CaseyIT's answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can also open Finder with the shortcut: Option + Command + Space.

Comment: This is the most precise answer.

Comment: FYI: this opens a "search" Finder window

Answer (score 5):

You can open a new Finder window with a searched for item in Spotlight with

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: Interesting, +1. Not exactly what I was looking for, but I just remembered that I can open a new window using `Command` + `N` without needing to open Spotlight.

Comment: Mnemonic: `r` as in `reveal`.

Comment: @Moshe: That does it, but requires Cmd-Tabbing to the Finder window (usually many Tab presses away for me) and then pressing Cmd-N.  It's not an eyes-off operation like I personally prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, apart from application shortcuts that @speedofmac told us about is there an other way to accomplish almost the same thing, except that you doesn't have to switch to finder or even open spotlight at all.

---

Custom global finder shortcut.

1. Open Automator.
2. Choose Service as document type.
3. Search for Launch Application or Library > Utilities > Launch Application.
4. Double-click or drag the action to the workflow.
5. At the top, select no input at "service receives" and make sure "any application" is selected.
6. Select new variable from the Action list.
7. As path select /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app.
8. Save the workflow and remember the name for later.
9. Open Keyboard, from Spotlight or System Preferences.
10. Select keyboard Shortcuts.
11. Locate Services from the left menu and then locate your own workflow and assign a key.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution with [BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/) (highly recommended, probably my most useful OSX Utility). I added a new global shortcut and chose the action "Send Shortcut to Specific Application". Then I chose the Finder application (thanks to Carl's answer above) at `/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app`. Then I ticked the "Bring app to front before sending the shortcut" option.

Now I have a global hotkey that switches to Finder and opens a new window. I have it mapped to <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> but I could just as easily have it mapped to a trackpad gesture or even a leap motion action!

Answer (score 0):

Crazy old post, but i solved it by writing a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

open -a Finder ~
```

Now just open the script using Spotlight.